# How do you place p tag on a new line when using aria-label breadcrumb?

Tags: html, css, navbar

I have a nav element and am trying to display text underneath that breadcrumb navbar instead of next to it. I've tried to add a `display: inline-block` line to my navbar property in CSS but I am still getting the same result.

It works when I had 2 or 3 `<br>` tags following the navbar, but I don't want to do that on every page. I'd like to use CSS.

Here is the snippet:

```css
.first {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav.breadcrumb {
  padding-top: 0.8em;
  padding-bottom: 0.8em;
  padding-left: 0.5em;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
  border: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 90%);
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: hsl(300, 14%, 97%);
  font-size: 14px;
  float: left;
  max-width: 45%;
}

nav.breadcrumb ol {
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  left: 0px;
}

nav.breadcrumb li {
  display: inline;
}

nav.breadcrumb li+li::before {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0.25em;
  transform: rotate(15deg);
  border-right: 0.1em solid currentColor;
  height: 0.8em;
  content: '';
}

nav.breadcrumb [aria-current="page"] {
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
  max-width: 45%;
}
```

```html
<nav aria-label="Breadcrumb" class="breadcrumb">
  <ol>
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/reamers">Reamers</a></li>
    <li>Jarno Reamers</li>
  </ol>
</nav>

<p class="first">Contact Us for <a href="https://gammons.com/reamers">reamers</a> or to ask about other offerings not listed below.</p>
```

[Here is the fiddle result.](https://jsfiddle.net/jheg1vcw/)

Comment: Remove `float: left` on the `nav` if you want it to take up the whole line.

Answer (score 2):

Delete `float: left` in `.nav.breadcrumb`

Answer (score 2):

On `nav.breadcrumb` add style `display: inline-block;` and remove `float: left`

Remove `display: inline-block;` from `.first`

```css
nav.breadcrumb {
    padding-top: 0.8em;
    padding-bottom: 0.8em;
    padding-left: 0.5em;
    padding-right: 0.5em;
    border: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 90%);
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: hsl(300, 14%, 97%);
    font-size: 14px;
    max-width: 45%;
    display: inline-block;
}

nav.breadcrumb ol {
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style: none;
    left: 0px;
}

nav.breadcrumb li {
    display: inline;
}

nav.breadcrumb li+li::before {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0.25em;
    transform: rotate(15deg);
    border-right: 0.1em solid currentColor;
    height: 0.8em;
    content: '';
}

nav.breadcrumb [aria-current="page"] {
    color: #000;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-decoration: none;
    max-width: 45%;
}
```

```html
<nav aria-label="Breadcrumb" class="breadcrumb">
    <ol>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/reamers">Reamers</a></li>
        <li>Jarno Reamers</li>
    </ol>
</nav>

<p class="first">Contact Us for <a href="https://gammons.com/reamers">reamers</a> or to ask about other offerings not listed below.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this achieve what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/w8ka032v/2/

```
.first {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```